# Imagens responsivas

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou montando um blog com o design responsivo e atualmente uso `width:100%` para redimensionar as imagens dentro da `div`.

```
.eMessage>.pimg>img{
width:100%;
-webkit-width: 100%; /*Chrome*/
-moz-width: 100%; /*Mozila*/
-ms-width: 100%; /*Internet Explorer*/
-o-width: 100%; /*Opera*/}
```

Mas as imagens são, às vezes, pesadas para um dispositivo móvel.

Vocês conhecem solução para que seja carregada uma imagem mais leve nos dispositivos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu usei o [picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) no meu site.

Basta incluir o ficheiro "picturefill.js" e marcar as imagens assim:

```
<span data-picture data-alt="A giant stone face at The Bayon temple in Angkor Thom, Cambodia">
    <span data-src="small.jpg"></span>
    <span data-src="medium.jpg"     data-media="(min-width: 400px)"></span>
    <span data-src="large.jpg"      data-media="(min-width: 800px)"></span>
    <span data-src="extralarge.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 1000px)"></span>

    <!-- Fallback content for non-JS browsers. Same img src as the initial, unqualified source element. -->
    <noscript>
        <img src="small.jpg" alt="A giant stone face at The Bayon temple in Angkor Thom, Cambodia">
    </noscript>
</span>
```

Se foram adicionadas imagens dinamicamente a' pagina (por javascript, por exemplo), basta chamar `picturefill();` para o plugin as detectar.

Existem outras opcoes, como o [HiSRC](https://github.com/teleject/hisrc): `<img src="200x100.png" data-1x="400x200.png" data-2x="800x400.png">`. O HiSRC, para alem de testar a resolucao do dispositivo, tambem testa a qualidade da internet. Se a ligacao for fraca, ele vai usar uma imagem de qualidade mais baixa, para acelerar o carregamento da pagina.

Existe uma spreadsheet muito boa com as vantagens/desvantagens de varias ferramentas [aqui](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Al0lI17fOl9DdDgxTFVoRzFpV3VCdHk2NTBmdVI2OXc#gid=0), organizada pelo Chris Coyier, autor to css-tricks.com

Fontes: [Which responsive images solution should you use?](http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/) / [Choosing A Responsive Image Solution](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/08/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/)

**Editado**:

Existe uma comunidade que esta' a tentar fazer com que os browsers adoptem um novo element `<picture>` para suportar imagens responsivas nativamente: [Responsive Images Community Group](http://responsiveimages.org/).

Comment: Obrigado a todos que tentaram me ajudar, mas o `picturefill.js` apesar de ser mais complexo, é o método mais eficiente de ter varias imagens responsivas de acordo com a resolução da tela. Valeu @dcastro .

Answer (score 1):

Você pode puxar as imagens no CSS. Você usa uma média pra cada imagem, ai você vai puxar imagens editadas do PhotoShop ou de outro editor, para que cada imagem fique menor que a outra pra cada resolução.

Você pode criar de vários tipos:

`<a class="foto"> </a>`

ou

`<p class="foto"> </p>`

no CSS você pode pôr

```
@media all and (min-width:1025px) and (max-width:1366px){

.foto {
   display: block;
   background:url(foto.jpg);

   width:350px;
   height:200px;
   position: relative;  }}

@media all and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px){

.foto {
   display: block;
   background:url(foto_02.jpg);
   width:250px;
   height:150px;
   position: relative;  }}
```

Comment: Alguns browsers vao fazer download das 2 imagens: [Media Query & Asset Downloading Results](http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/)

Answer (score 0):

Também ajuda muito no desempenho diminuir o peso das imagens usando algum complemento como o imagemin que está disponível para [Grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin) e para [Gulp](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin) caso ajude no seu caso.